# Issue with Java in Mac OS X 10.7.4

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, java

I bought Mac Pro, I have been trapped with Java. I am a Unix and Windows user.

I've never faced these kind of issues before with Java. Previously, I had some issues with the Java path, which I asked here and that got resolved. After that, I upgraded to 10.7 from 10.6 and I lost Java.

I had installed Java several times after that, JDK 6 and JDK 7, both. But, neither works.

Even the `java -version` command does not work after installing.

When I am trying to download the dmg file from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1515 and trying to install, it says "Newer version already installed".

Is there a way, I can get it resolved?

Edit: Doing `ls` in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework gives me no output.

Comment: What happens if you run the **Java Preferences** application in */Applications/Utilities/*?

Comment: It says , this application is not installed . If I try to install it , it finds java . After sometime, its shows a dialog which says "can not find java" .

Comment: What happens if you install the Oracle JDK 7 ?